# Oracle APEX 5 Select List Error ORA-01400

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

i have a Problem with Oracle APEX 5.

I have a Popup with Textareas and with a Select List. I can write the Data of the Textareas without Problem into my Database, but i can not write the Data of my Select list into my Database. I alway get the Error ORA-01400 Server Error Insert of NULL imposible.

I also tried to write Hard data in the Table so i Changed the PLSQL to:

```
begin
INSERT INTO STATUS_TO_CHANGE (CHANGE_ID, CHANGE_STATUS_ID)
VALUES (:P2_CHANGE_ID, '43');
end;
```

and it worked without Problems :(

Maybe someone can help me :O

I use a own button to save the Textarea and a own button for the select list.

Code of my Dynamic Action:

```
begin
INSERT INTO STATUS_TO_CHANGE (CHANGE_ID, CHANGE_STATUS_ID)
VALUES (:P2_CHANGE_ID, :P2_STATUS_DESCRIPTION);
end;
```

Name of the Select List: P2_Status_Description

[Select List with save Button .jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki4GY.png)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD9bP.png)[Data in the Table Change_Status which is shown in the LOV in the Select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc35H.png)

Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see images right now.

Anyway: this is, I believe, a "Execute PL/SQL Code" dynamic action, right? You put that `BEGIN-END` block into the "PL/SQL Code", but - did you put `P2_CHANGE_ID` and `P2_STATUS_DESCRIPTION` into **Items to Submit**? If not, do it and then try again.

Comment: OMG. Thank you it worked. I created the Dynamic Action so many times that i forgot this option. Thank you very much! :)